# Make 7 year ago prints compatible with now

Tags: c, printf

I'm reading the book The Art Of Exploitation and there is a program called `memory_segments.c` which just demostrante to us how the memory segments works, the heap, the stack and etc. But when I try to compile the program it seems like that the printing isn't more compatible with now. I use `gcc` 10.2.0 to compile my C code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int global_initialized_var = 5;

int main() 
{
   printf("global_initialized_var is at address 0x%08x\n", &global_initialized_var);
   // ... more prints, removed just to make code shorter

   return 0;
}  
// warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

The author of the book's output:

```
...
global_initialized_var is at address 0x080497ec
...
```

**What is the alternative for `0x%08x`? And why does `0x%08x` no longer work?**

Comment: Stackoverflow is a bad place to learn programming. Consider reading a good C book.

Answer (score 3):

1. `%x` prints integer values not pointers. It is Undefined Behaviour. To print pointers use `printf("%p", (void *)pointer);`
2. The integer types which should be used when converting pointers are `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`. For differences between pointers `ptrdiff_t`
3. To print `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` you need to use `PRIdPTR PRIiPTR PRIoPTR PRIuPTR PRIxPTR PRIXPTR` printf formats. Example:

```
uintptr_t p = SOME_VALUE;
printf("UINTPTR_T printed as hex: %" PRIxPTR "\n", p);
```

Comment: Can you suggest me a good book for learning these things? I know you are good.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the alternative for 0x%08x?

To properly print a pointer value, use `%p` with `void*` pointer:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)&global_initialized_var);
```

It will use some implementation-specific form of printing it, most commonly it's the same as `%#x` format. If you want to get a specific numeric representation of the pointer, the best standard way would be to use the biggest possible integer type:

```
printf("%#jx\n", (uintmax_t)(uintptr_t)&global_initialized_var);
```

However, usually you can/want to just cast the pointer value to an integer and print it, as usually it's only for temporary debugging purposes, just like:

```
// Could truncate pointer value!
printf("%#llx\n", (unsigned long long)&global_initialized_var);
printf("%#lx\n", (unsigned long)&global_initialized_var);
printf("%#x\n", (unsigned)&global_initialized_var);
```

Note that `unsigned` has **at least** 16 bits, `long` has **at least** 32-bits and `long long` has **at least** 64-bits. Platforms are nowadays 64-bit, pointers are 64-bit - anyway, prefer the widest available type when printing pointer value, to be portable - thus the use `uintmax_t` above. It was common on unix platforms to use `long` to cast to/from pointers - on 64-bit unix `long` has 64-bits, while on windows it has 32-bits.

Comment: Why do you have to use `(void*)`? What is the type of `&var` in the first place?

Comment: The type of `&var` is "pointer to the type of var". E.g: `int *foo;` : now the type of `&foo` is `int*` (pointer to `int` c). The `(void*)`  is needed with `%p` because the C standard specifies this, but on most platforms you get away if you omit `(void*)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Okay thanks. And `biggest possible integer type`, seems like that each one is only 8 bytes, what  is the meaning of `(uintmax_t)(uintptr_t)`? Each one of them is only 8 bytes, how can it be the biggest possible integer?

Comment: What's the difference if `long` is 8 bytes? Is there any difference between `uintmax_t` and `unsigned long long`?

Comment: KamilCuk, Interesting:  `(uintmax_t)&global_initialized_var` is UB if the address is out of `uintmax_t` range.  `(uintptr_t)&global_initialized_var` fails to compile if `uintptr_t` does not exist (likely because there is no  integer type capable).  I suppose better a compile fail than UB.

Comment: To print (u)intptr_t you need special formats like for (u)intXX_t

Answer (score 0):

> why does 0x%08x no longer work?

It is (and was) UB due to mis-matched types.

`%x` expects an `unsigned`.   `&global_initialized_var` is a pointer.